# A weird issue about converting a reference type to another by using operator reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  int& rf = reinterpret_cast<int&>((int&&)1);
}
```

In this example, `GCC` and `MSVC` do not accept this code. Instead, `Clang` compiles it successfully. The result is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/KK5W95).

Through researching the relevant rule, the corresponding rule is:
[expr.reinterpret.cast#11](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#11)

> A glvalue of type T1, designating an object x, can be cast to the type “reference to T2” if an expression of type “pointer to T1” can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to T2” using a reinterpret_­cast. **The result is that of `*reinterpret_­cast<T2 *>(p)` where p is a pointer to x of type “pointer to T1”.** No temporary is created, no copy is made, and no constructors ([class.ctor]) or conversion functions ([class.conv]) are called.

Look at this rule, I think this rule is so vague. It says the result is that of `*reinterpret_­cast<T2 *>(p)`. The rule for de-referencing pointer is defined as:
[expr.unary#op-1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#op-1)

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and **the result is an lvalue** referring to the object or function to which the expression points.

So, according to the rule [expr.unary#op-1], the value category of `*reinterpret_­cast<T2 *>(p)` is lvalue. And the rule [expr.reinterpret.cast#11] only requires that the source pointer type can be converted to the destination pointer type by using `reinterpret_cast`, there are no other requirement such as value category for its operand.  From this point, I think **Clang** gives a right process. Because the result is lvalue, hence it can be bound to lvalue reference.

Now, give a little modification to the first example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  int& rf = reinterpret_cast<int&>(1);
}
```

Then, [three compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/ovjaYM) all reject this example. What's the hell? The difference with the first example is the operand of `reinterpret_cast` here is prvalue. Merely,  this difference make `Clang` don't accept this code?  According to [expr#10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#10)

> Whenever a prvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a glvalue for that operand, the temporary materialization conversion is applied to convert the expression to an xvalue.

As said in the above rule, **temporary materialization conversion** should apply to prvalue `1` to make it be a glvalue. After this conversion, I don't see that this example has any difference with the first example. Why `Clang` now reject it?

Let us continue consider the third example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  int&& rf = reinterpret_cast<int&&>(1);
}
```

This time `GCC` accept this example while the other two compiler report an error, the [result](https://godbolt.org/z/Te4xac) is here.

If change the declaration to `int&& rf = reinterpret_cast<int&&>((int&&)1);` then `Clang` will accept that.

In addition, the [expr.reinterpret.cast#11] has said that the result of converting reference type to another by using `reinterpret_cast` always a **lvalue** (**`*reinterpret_­cast<T2 *>(p)`**), it hints we cannot use a rvalue reference type to bind to the result. Isn't it?

These examples are thought out when I read the [expr.reinterpret.cast#11]. Different compilers give very different result. It's weird. I also think that [expr.reinterpret.cast#11] gives a very vague wording. It didn't say the requirement of value category of the operand when we give a rvalue reference or lvalue reference type. It just says that as long as these pointer types can be converted. The rule also didn't say what value category the result is. We can only infer that its value category is lvalue through the expression `*reinterpret_­cast<T2 *>(p)`.

How to interpret these issues. Is it a defect of [expr.reinterpret.cast#11]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, according to the rule [expr.unary#op-1], the value category of `*reinterpret_­cast<T2 *>(p)` is lvalue.

No, because [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#11) doesn't say the reference-casting expression is equivalent in every way to `*reinterpret_cast<T2*>(p)`. It says the expression's *result* is the same as that expression's. Here "result" refers to [[basic.lval]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prop#basic.lval-5):

> The *result* of a glvalue is the entity denoted by the expression.

The value category of the `reinterpret_cast` expression is defined only by [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#1),

> The result of the expression `reinterpret_­cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` to type `T`. If `T` is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, the result is an lvalue; if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is an xvalue; otherwise, the result is a prvalue and ....

So `reinterpret_cast<int&>((int&&)1)` has value category lvalue because the type `int&` is an lvalue reference type, not because of the unary `*` rule. Its result is the object created by the temporary materialization of prvalue `1`.

> `reinterpret_cast<int&>(1)`
> ... **temporary materialization conversion** should apply to prvalue `1` to make it be a glvalue

No - the only part of [basic.reinterpret.cast] which could possibly describe `reinterpret_cast<int&&>(1)` would again be [paragraph 11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#11), for converting a glvalue to a reference type. But its last sentence includes "No temporary is created", so the temporary materialization is not allowed.

So both `reinterpret_cast<int&>(1)` and `reinterpret_cast<int&&>(1)` are ill-formed, and gcc is incorrect in accepting `reinterpret_cast<int&&>(1)` without any error or warning.

Comment: "I think implies that a temporary materialization conversion never applies to the operand of reinterpret_cast".  I don't think so. As paragraph 1 says, the value category is determined by the destination type.  The meaning of wording after `otherwise` means, if the result of `reinterpret_cast` is a prvalue, then only these listed conversions could be applied to the expression `v`. It does not say that only these listed conversions can apply to expression `v` in any case.  After all, the function of these listed conversions are all used to read the **value** to form a prvalue.

Comment: I agree it's not entirely as clear as it could be. But it's interesting that paragraph 1 specifically mentions the usual three glvalue-to-prvalue conversions but not the usual prvalue-to-xvalue conversion.

Comment: I think it should be considered as a wording defect.  From the behavior of `Clang`, your opinion is right. However, honestly, I don't read the subtle from paragraph 1(as your interpretation). It neither says temporary materialization conversion is permitted or prohibited.  As a common rule "Whenever a prvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a glvalue for that operand". Hence, I don't know the rule [expr.reinterpret.cast#11] is saying whether it expects a glvalue or the original expression should be a glvalue? which is the right intent here? It's vague here.

Comment: Oh, wait. Paragraph 11 says "no temporary is created". That's more relevant than everything else I quoted, and I'd say definitely rules out the temporary materialization.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the temporary meant between two different types, reinterprest_cast cannot invoke any user-defined conversion to create a destination type temporary object.  Presumably, the temporary is your meaning. Anyhow, Merry Christmas.